# Outlook appointment exception gets locked out for editing body/description

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I have my Outlook-Addin which talks to my server.

It's in MAPI C++, developed using Visual Studio.

The problem is described in below steps.

1. Create recurring appointment in outlook/web client.
2. From Web client, create exception to the recurring appointment by editing body for lets say 2nd occurrence. (Earlier this body was not getting synced to outlook as I had not used PR_FExceptionalBody property to true. Now I set this property to true when I get exception modified).
3. Now from Outlook, create one more exception, lets say 3rd occurrence of the same appointment and modify body of that. Sync it to server/web client.
4. Go back to 2nd occurrence in OUTLOOK, which we had modified in step 2 and try to modify the body. It shows locked and can't edit the appointment. The appointment page opens but can't edit body.

If I don't set PR_FExceptionalBody (As described in [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidfexceptionalbody-canonical-property) by Microsoft) property to true, outlook doesn't show the modified body for the exceptions created. It displays only the body of recurring series. If I use that property to make it true. It updated body correctly for exception but previous exception gets locked out.

Is there any other property which I need to set or anything I am doing wrong here? Any help/pointers?

Comment: Have you trie4d to compare the good (created and modified by Outlook) and bad (created/modified by your code) appointments using OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: HI @Dmitry, Thanks for your response. Yes, I did and found these things extra in the appointment which gets locked.

Comment: @Dimtry Plz have the extra property here for locked appt. Using Outlook Spy
==========================================

0x80B9 AppointmentSequence PT_LONG 0
0x812F  (lID=0x85D7) PT_LONG 1
0x8130  PidNameContentType PT_UNICODE multipart/alternative;
PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX (or ptagReplServerInfo) PT_BINARY
PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX_TRACKING
PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W

PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W

Comment: I don't think these matter much. Do you see embedded message attachments?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, Code wise yes I see it. Is there a way to check it thro OutlookSpy?

Comment: Of course - GetAttachmentTable tab in the IMessage window. If you need to open the embedded message attachment, right click on the PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ and select IMAPIProp::OpenProperty, select IID_IMessage.,

Comment: @Dimtry, Yes, When I open any message as series it shows attachments. e.g. I had created 5 occurrence of appointment and out of that I had created 3 as exception. So GetAttachmentTable tab shows 3 attachments. I analyzed all the attachments properties but everything is same except attachment number which is fine. So stuck up what should I do now. Just one more question. Is there a way to attach body of exception without FExceptionalBody to true? Or this property is mandatory for displaying modified body of exception in recurring series?

Comment: Body must be set on the embedded message attachment. Have you tried to open PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ as IMessage?

Comment: Hello @Dimtry, Yes I have set the body in code to PR_HTML property, Because without any change, if i just set property FExceptionalBody to true it starts showing modified body for exceptions and if i dont' sest FExceptionalBody property it doesn't show modified property, instead it shows body of appt series In IMessage->GetAttachmentTable tab for the attachment I can see PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ but it's not opening. I mean it's not showing anything, what it shows is property id, schema url, type, tag num and value as hex (here - 04482000)

Comment: Are all 3 flavors updated (plain text / RTF / HTML)? To open the embedded message, you need to open the attachment first by double clicking the attachment in the GetAttachmentTable tab.

Comment: Yes, Updated all three flavors. Also to open exception attachment I did same. Like go to IMessage->GetAttachmentTable tab-> select the attachment->Double click it->check PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ. What I believe is, the code is updating the body properly that's the reason it gets displayed when I set the property FExceptionalBody to true. Else it wouldn't hav displayed updated body for exception. So I doubt of it being not getting updated properly. But the problem is if I set FExceptionalBody to true, that particular exception gets locked for further editing. Is there any property responsible for it?